# how to call ibm watson api from .net core

Tags: .net, curl, ibm-watson, personality-insights

I'm trying to call the watson personality insight api, after looking around it seems the solution is to make a .net equivalent of the following curl request. I'm pretty new to this and was wondering if i could get guidance or be pointed to relevant tutorials.

```
curl -X POST -u "{username}:{password}"
--header "Content-Type: application/json"
--data-binary @profile
"https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/personality-insights/api/v3/profile?version=2016-10-20&consumption_preferences=true&raw_scores=true"
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use the [Watson Developer Cloud .NET Standard SDK](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/dotnet-standard-sdk/tree/development/src/IBM.WatsonDeveloperCloud.PersonalityInsights). Install the Personality Insights service via NuGet using

```
Install-Package IBM.WatsonDeveloperCloud.PersonalityInsights -Pre
```

Instantiate the service

```
// create a Personality Insights Service instance
PersonalityInsightsService _personalityInsights = new PersonalityInsightsService();

// set the credentials
_personalityInsights.SetCredential("<username>", "<password>");
```

Call the service

```
var results = _personalityInsights.GetProfile(ProfileOptions.CreateOptions()
                                                         .WithTextPlain()
                                                         .AsEnglish()
                                                         .AcceptJson()
                                                         .AcceptEnglishLanguage()
                                                         .WithBody("some text"));
```

In a **future release** you will be able to call the service using named parameters instead of building options.

```
var results = _personalityInsights.GetProfile(
        "<input>", 
        "<content-type>", 
        "<content-language>", 
        "<accept>", 
        "<accept-language>",
        "<raw-scores>",
        "<csv-headers>"
        "<consumption-preferences>",
        "<version>"
    );
```

Answer (score 2):

in this case are you use curl to call the API? According your example...

Call the Personality Insights by providing the `username` and `password` that are provided in the **service credentials** for the service instance that you want to use. The API uses `HTTP` basic authentication.

**For authentication:**

```
curl -u "{username}":"{password}"
"https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/personality-insights/api/v3/{method}"
```

Bluemix collects data from all requests and uses the data to improve the Watson services.

**Request logging:**

```
curl -u "{username}":"{password}"
--header "X-Watson-Learning-Opt-Out: true"
"https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/personality-insights/api/v3/{method}"
```

**Methods to call and get the response:**

```
curl -X POST -u "{username}:{password}"
--header "Content-Type: application/json"
--data-binary @profile.json
"https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/personality-insights/api/v3/profile?version=2016-10-20&consumption_preferences=true&raw_scores=true"
```

IBM Watson API's uses standard HTTP response codes to indicate whether a method completed successfully.

- 200-level response always indicates success.
- 400-level response indicates some sort of failure.
- 500-level response typically indicates an internal system error.

Check this [documentation](https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/personality-insights/api/v3/#methods) from IBM to develop, has all examples how to call and if have errors the reason for that. And [this](https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/doc/personality-insights/) for verify how to work and how to use.

Demo [here](https://personality-insights-livedemo.mybluemix.net/), you can fork from github if you want.